# The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: sharepoint, dll, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Windows 10, VS2013 professional
Window phone silverlight 8.1 application.

The error is:

```
The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.
System.InvalidOperationException: Item named 'xamls/simplelogin.xaml' of type 'System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream' cannot be added to the resource file because it is not serializable.
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.WriteResources(ReaderInfo reader, IResourceWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.WriteResources(ReaderInfo reader, String filename)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.ProcessFile(String inFile, String outFileOrDir)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.Run(TaskLoggingHelper log, ITaskItem[] assemblyFilesList, List`1 inputs, List`1 satelliteInputs, List`1 outputs, Boolean sourcePath, String language, String namespacename, String resourcesNamespace, String filename, String classname, Boolean publicClass, Boolean extractingResWFiles, String resWOutputDirectory)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.Run(TaskLoggingHelper log, ITaskItem[] assemblyFilesList, List`1 inputs, List`1 satelliteInputs, List`1 outputs, Boolean sourcePath, String language, String namespacename, String resourcesNamespace, String filename, String classname, Boolean publicClass, Boolean extractingResWFiles, String resWOutputDirectory)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext() CarManagerWpApp
```

When i remove the "Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Phone.Auth.UI" reference, everything is allright. Unfortunately, this dll is crutial for me. I have seen a lot of 'The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly' errors on net, none of solutions helped me.

Anyone has any idea? Thank you

Comment: I have also been able to reproduce this issue on my laptop running windows 8.1